# get Scanner current line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

In my project, I recieve an already initiated Scanner and I need to find out its currnt line.  for example:

```
public boolean foo(Scanner scan) {
if (scan.getCurrentLine().equals("Hi Hello") {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

I'm a bit lost. Any suggestions?

Comment: `Scanner` does not offer an API to retrieve a line without consuming it. If you get a scanner from some other place and you are not supposed to advance the line, there is nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has the line been read before?

If not, then the syntax is `scan.nextLine();`

If you can anticipate needing the string, try keeping and passing the string to the method.

Also, just to note, the `.equals()` method returns a boolean, so you can say `return scan.nextLine().equals("Hi Hello")` (or `return str.equals("Hi Hello");` if using the `String` version).

Comment: What I meant, is that the line **was** read before. You recieve a scanner instance that was initiated with a data file, already read a part of it(but you don't know what part), and you need to know where it **currently** is.

Comment: In that case, you can save all of the data from the scanner in a `LinkedList<String>` like in (`while(scan.hasNextLine()) list.add(scan.nextLine());`)and pass along the last entry in the list to the foo method (`list.getLast()`).

Comment: Since reading the file doesn't change it, if the file isn't gigabytes big, holding every line at once may be the most efficient way. If it is gigabytes in size, perhaps Java isn't the best language to read it with.